# How to create a function to return variables in php

Tags: php, arrays, function, loops

I want to create a function by which i can get variables..

for example

```php
$var = array("site_name" => "site_value", "site_des" => "site_value2");

foreach ($var as $key => $val){
$$key = $val;
}
echo $site_name; // print site_value
```

this code works but when i insert it in a function like

```php
function get_var(){
$var = array("site_name" => "site_value", "site_des" => "site_value2");
foreach ($var as $key => $val){
$$key = $val;
}
}
```

and i want to get this vars in a function link

```php
function get_other(){
get_var();
return 'hi '.$site_name; // hi site_value
}
```

Actual i want global variable in function but i have a large no of global variables and i have to write each global variable in function each time when i make a function.

so if there is any other good method to do this please let me know..

Comment: This is not possible. You can only return one variable from a function, to manipulate more than one you have to use the `global` keyword.

Comment: You can however place all your functions and the variables in a class, then you can reference them as `$this->site_name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

```
$var = array("site_name" => "site_value", "site_des" => "site_value2");
extract($var);

echo $site_name; // outputs: site_value
```

Be sure to check the **flags** section in the documentation on how to deal with overwriting local variables or prefixing the keys in your array.

A little example. Since your `$var` could come for anywhere and basically change our global or local vars, thus making your code unsafe, you can for instance make sure to only extract known vars `EXTR_IF_EXISTS` or you can choose to prefix all the vars:

```
extract($var, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "ext");
echo $ext_site_name;
```

Answer (score -1):

If i'm reading You correctly, you want to use $GLOBALS superglobal array to set new global variable like this:

```
function test()
{
  $GLOBALS [ "test" ] = "value";
}
test();
print ( "My variable: " . $test . "\n" );
```

Check above code [at codepad](http://codepad.org/4obSr4Ie). It outputs `My variable: value`.

Your code then could looks like:

```
function get_var(){
  $var = array("site_name" => "site_value", "site_des" => "site_value2");
  foreach ($var as $key => $val){
    $GLOBALS[$key] = $val;
  }
}
function get_other(){
  get_var();
  return 'hi '.$GLOBALS["site_name"]; // hi site_value
}
```

EDIT: I've created codepad for Your code also, [check it here](http://codepad.org/m8VlgLHs).

Comment: Dear downvoter, please clarify why downvote. I could make better answer, if You explain my mistakes.